# What's the difference between e2fsck and fsck and which one I should use?

Tags: fsck

I got this error message when running dmesg

```
EXT3-fs (sdd1): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
EXT4-fs (sdc1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
Adding 4194296k swap on /dev/sdd2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4194296k SSD
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs (loop0): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
```

sdd seems to be running fine. That's the main partition.
sda to sdc doesn't work. Should I umount and fo fsck? But which fsck I should use? e2fsck? e4fsck? Which one? I am using ext4 here.

I have no idea what loop0 is.

Looks like the system is pretty badly set up.
    EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode

I've heard I can do shutdown -rf . Someone have done that. The system is back online but I still got this message. What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fsck` is the original name for this tool. When new file systems came out they would need specific tools for each one. So `fsck` just acts as a frontend and will call the appropriate filesystem *fsck for operations that it's not able to do itself.

*excerpt from the fsck man page*

> fs-specific-options
>
> ```
>     Options which are not understood by fsck are passed to the 
>     filesystem-specific checker.  These arguments must  not
>     take  arguments,  as  there is no way for fsck to be able to 
>     properly guess which arguments take options and which don't.
>
>     Options and arguments which follow the -- are treated as file 
>     system-specific options to be  passed  to  the  file
>     system-specific checker.
>
>     Please note that fsck is not designed to pass arbitrarily 
>     complicated options to filesystem-specific checkers.  If
>     you're doing something complicated, please just execute the 
>     filesystem-specific checker  directly.   If  you  pass
>     fsck  some horribly complicated option and arguments, and it 
>     doesn't do what you expect, don't bother reporting it
>     as a bug.  You're almost certainly doing something that you 
>     shouldn't be doing with fsck.
> ```

Most of the normal operations can be handled just by `fsck`.

#### other tools?

A quick look on my Fedora 14 system shows the following fsck* tools:

```
$ fsck
fsck          fsck.ext2     fsck.ext4     fsck.msdos    fsck.vfat     
fsck.cramfs   fsck.ext3     fsck.ext4dev  fsck.ntfs     fsck.xfs
```

This `locate` command shows even more:

```
$ locate fsck|grep "^/sbin"
/sbin/dosfsck
/sbin/e2fsck
/sbin/fsck
/sbin/fsck.cramfs
/sbin/fsck.ext2
/sbin/fsck.ext3
/sbin/fsck.ext4
/sbin/fsck.ext4dev
/sbin/fsck.msdos
/sbin/fsck.ntfs
/sbin/fsck.vfat
/sbin/fsck.xfs
```

Between the 2 listings you can see that pretty much every file system type has its own fsck* tool. A few of the tools are multi-purpose such as `dos2fsck`:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/|grep fsck | grep dos
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   54424 Apr  5  2011 dosfsck
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Aug  3  2011 fsck.msdos -> dosfsck
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Aug  3  2011 fsck.vfat -> dosfsck
```

#### References

- [fsck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)